# Groovy, How to do 2 phase commit? Is Sql.withTransaction can manage transaction scope accross multiple databases?

Tags: sql, grails, groovy, transactions, 2phase-commit

Well, I think my question says it all. I need to know if Groovy SQL supports two phase commits. I'm actually programming a Grails Service where I want to define a method which does the following:

Get SQL instance for Database 1,
Get SQL instance for Databsae 2,

Open a transaction some how:
Within the transaction call two different stored procedures on each database respectively.
Then commit some how or rollback on both connection if needed.

I didn't find any useful information yet about this anywhere on the web.

I've to program two phase commits any way, so even if this is supported by some other means (e.g. getting help from spring artifacts and use them in grails), please guide me. This has become a show stopper for me at the moment.

Note: I'm using MySQL and mysql-connector driver.
Thanks,
Alam Sher

Answer (score 0):

The current version of MySQL seems to support two-phase commits as long as you're using the INNODB storage engine. There are other restrictions.

[MySQL reference for two-phase commit](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/xa.html)

Groovy added "transaction support" in 1.7, but I'm not certain what they mean by that.